# Flag a wrong but highly voted comment?

Tags: discussion, flags

The reason to flag a comment in the help center is :

- rude or offensive
- not constructive / off-topic — a comment that does not try to improve the post it appears on, or which introduces a topic unrelated to the question or answer
- obsolete — a comment that is no longer relevant because it has been addressed by an edit to the post, clarified by additional comments, or contains no context because it references deleted content
- too chatty — anything that's not relevant to the question or answer

But this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python/1267892#1267892)'s **fourth visible** comment is wrong and has 30 votes now which may mislead many people.

This is 'obsolete'? And if I flag it, I must assume that the moderator know it or try it, which is not always true.

So what to do?

Comment: So if none of the obectives you mentioned applies, you don't flag it, or take _other_ and explain your concerns to get a moderators attend.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't actually look that wrong.  When I RTFM, it does mention that `__future__.division` matters.  The comments seem appropriate enough to warn the reader.  You can always ask a question about it and post a comment on the answer with a link to the Q+A.

Comment: I agree comment is misleading and wrong.

Answer (score 19):

This is a question of expertise in the programming language, not moderation.

**Don't ask moderators to judge technical content.**

In the particular case you linked, there's a follow-on comment from another user, almost as highly upvoted, pointing out the earlier comment is wrong.  The best thing to do is to upvote that comment.

If there weren't already an existing comment, the best thing to do would be to post a counter-example on an online compiler, and link that example in a comment pointing out the earlier one was wrong.

Comment: Not really sure about that. A highly voted question should be technically OK, not just according to some rules. I am taking a much more technical approach, when judging content than you suggest it. I'm also usually skipping everything I don't have knowledge of. Until now I thought that was the way how StackOverflow is working or should work.

Comment: @csabinho: Questions are even easier to deal with by voting, because they can be downvoted.  Wrong comments present a problem that they can't be downvoted... but upvoting a competing comment is an effective workaround.  There's no role for a moderator to play here.  But you aren't a moderator, so I'm not sure how your content-judging habits are relevant.  Voting *should* reflect technical correctness.  This meta post was about bypassing the voting processes and having a moderator simply delete stuff.

Comment: In my opinion there should be a flag that deals with wrong answers! But I know that there isn't one at the moment!

Comment: @csabinho: This meta post isn't even talking about answers!  And no, there shouldn't be a flag like that, because flags don't go to subject matter experts and only subject matter experts can assess correctness of an answer.

Comment: It seems to me that you're relying a bit too much on crowd intelligence, or in other words "the crowd can't be wrong". Of course I understood that this post is about something else, but it's similar.

Comment: @csabinho: The crowd CAN be wrong, but that happens less often than a moderator being wrong about a technical issue.  The whole site is built on the premise that voting by the crowd is meaningful.  Stack Overflow isn't going to change that because you object to relying on crowd intelligence.

Comment: In my opinion there are two aspects of moderation. The one side is the part where you don't need any knowledge of the content you're moderating, the other side is the "technical moderation". But of course I'll have to accept that my thoughts are not the way StackExchange and StackOverflow works! Interestingly some time ago it was possible to flag low quality content.

Comment: @csabinho: Even then, "low quality" was never about being *wrong in technical details*.  It was for things that were incomprehensible (such as gobbledygook generated by a Markov model) or lacked explanation (perhaps just a link with no explanation), things like that.

Comment: As long as there are only upvotes and not downvotes for comments, it's hard for me to stomach this policy.

Answer (score 5):

Wrong content falls under the 'not relevant' bit of **obsolete**. You can flag such comments as No Longer Needed (NLN). Mods will likely delete the comment due to adherence to the philosophy that comments are 'temporary Post-It notes'... not intended or designed to stick around forever. I have ...a lot... of experience with flagging comments as NLN and I can tell you from my helpful flag rate that even *correct* comments are not immune to NLN deletion.

You are correct in that a comment suggesting a technically wrong thing does sometimes require technical knowledge to confirm, and that could cause a moderator to decline such a NLN flag or otherwise not delete the comment. If such a NLN flag is declined, then you can proceed with a custom moderator flag describing in detail how the comment is wrong and thus not useful/relevant.

Remember that comments are ephemeral anyway; if informational/expository comments are that useful to readers, they should be an edit to the post. **Keeping comments around forever is the exception, not the rule.**